# How to change color of angular-chart.js on a certain condition?

Tags: angularjs, angular-chart

I am generating a graph using angular-chart.js
The bars of the graph should be colored according to condition.

If data returned is greater than 5 i want a certain color,else other color.
My graph is generated but with random colors. Also I console Logged $scope.colors, it shows the fillcolor array populated with proper values yet I can see random colors

Javascript

```
$scope.options = {scales: {xAxes: [{stacked: true}]}};
$scope.colors = [{fillColor:[]}]

$scope.generateGraph = function () {

    $http.get(url).success(function(res){
           for(i=0;i<res.data.length-1;i++){
            console.log(res.data[i])
              if(res.data[i] > 5){
                            $scope.colors[0].fillColor[i]="#FF0000"
                        }else{
                            $scope.colors[0].fillColor[i]="#00FF00"
                        }

           }

        $scope.labels = res.labels;
         $scope.data = res.data;  
    });

};
```

HTML

```
<canvas  id="bar" class="chart chart-bar" chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels" chart-series="series" chart-options="options" chart-colors = "colors" chart-click = "onClick">
 </canvas>
```